# Why can the ListNode example (Scala website) handle different types?

Tags: scala, type-parameter, lower-bound

The [ListNode example](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/137), taken from Scalas homepage goes like this:

```
case class ListNode[+T](h: T, t: ListNode[T]) {
  def head: T = h
  def tail: ListNode[T] = t
  def prepend[U >: T](elem: U): ListNode[U] =
    ListNode(elem, this)
}
```

With this class, we can create objects like:

```
val empty: ListNode[Null] = ListNode(null, null)
val strList: ListNode[String] = empty.prepend("hello")
                                     .prepend("world")
val anyList: ListNode[Any] = strList.prepend(12345)
```

As we can see, we can prepend an integer value to a `String` node. I guess, this works because the type parameter `U` will be automatically set to `Any`, when given the integer to the `prepend` method (because `Int` is not a supertype of `String`).

When trying this with an own lower bound example, I will get an error:

```
scala> class E[T >: String]
defined class E

scala> new E[Any]
res1: E[Any] = E@135f0a

scala> new E[Int]
<console>:11: error: type arguments [Int] do not conform to class E's type param
eter bounds [T >: String]
      val res2 =
          ^
<console>:12: error: type arguments [Int] do not conform to class E's type param
eter bounds [T >: String]
              new E[Int]
                  ^
```

Why is the type `Int` here not automatically seen as type `Any` like in the `ListNode` example ?

---

**UPDATE 1**: This also works (without explicitley saying the new `ListNode` should be of type `Any`)

```
scala> val empty: ListNode[Null] = ListNode(null, null)
empty: example.listNode.ListNode[Null] = ListNode(null,null)

scala> empty.prepend("hello").prepend("world")
res0: example.listNode.ListNode[java.lang.String] = ListNode(world,ListNode(hell
o,ListNode(null,null)))

scala> val strList: ListNode[String] = empty.prepend("hello").prepend("world")
strList: example.listNode.ListNode[String] = ListNode(world,ListNode(hello,ListN
ode(null,null)))

scala> strList.prepend(12345)
res1: example.listNode.ListNode[Any] = ListNode(12345,ListNode(world,ListNode(he
llo,ListNode(null,null))))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get the above error because `Int` is not a supertype of `String`.

Note that in the `ListNode` code above, `String` is a supertype of `Null` (see [class hierarchy](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/images/scalaHierarchy.jpg)), and `Any` is a supertype of `String` (as you rightly pointed out).

I would guess the confusions is caused by comparing two operations that are not really the same: `new E[Int]` instantiates the class with the type parameter `Int`, which is not conformant to the lower bound `String` and hence fails.

In the `ListNode` code above, on the other hand, you call the `prepend` method that takes a supertype `U` of `T`. When creating `anyList`, `U` is (just as you guessed) resolved to `Any` since this is the only common supertype of `String` and `Int`, so you could think of it as not really passing an `Int` to it, but just some arbitrary instance of `Any` (which also happens to be of type `Int`).

Therefore,

```
val anyList: ListNode[Int] = strList.prepend(12345)
```

fails as well, as `strList.prepend(12345)` can only return `ListNode[Any]`.

Comment: Thank you. But why is no error thrown with the line 'strList.prepend(12345)', where an integer is clearly no supertype of a String ?

Comment: Because you generate a `ListNode[Any]`, which conforms to the lower bound. If you try `val anyList: ListNode[Int] = strList.prepend(12345)` this fails.

Comment: The `prepend` call also works without explicitly saying the result `ListNode` should be of type `Any`. So there seems to be an automatically setting behind it ? See Update 1 of my question for an example.

Comment: Yes, this is (at least for me) one of Scala's killer features - type inference. The compiler can figure this out automatically, so there is no need to annotate the value with an extra type (except for clarity/readability, maybe).

Comment: Thank you. I think we are getting closer to my question :-) Yes, I agree with your comment. But then, why is my example not automatically figured out to `Any` ? Why is Scala acting here differently ?

Comment: This is because you _specifically_ instantiate `E` with type parameter `Int`, and this cannot be done. Simply speaking, type inference only fills out the blanks, but there is no ambiguity in `new E[Int]` and hence no blanks to fill out (see 2nd & 3rd paragraph in my answer). Imagine you would say `val x = new E[Int]` and only later find out that `x` is actually not of that type. This would be pretty strange, right?

Comment: Just for completeness: you can 'disable' this kind of type inference by specifying to which type `U` should resolve. Just try `strList.prepend[Int](12345)` in the interpreter (this fails) and `strList.prepend[Any](12345)` (this works).

Comment: Thank you very much - that helped me understanding my problem. So the 'blank' was the type parameter `U`, which was filled out by Scala. In my example, in contrast, I did already specify this and Scala had no chance to fill it by itself.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing one thing that is fundamentally different: passing the `Int` type. Let's make the original code break, as an example:

```
scala> val anyList: ListNode[Any] = strList.prepend[Int](12345)
<console>:11: error: type arguments [Int] do not conform to method prepend's type parameter bounds [U >: String]
       val anyList: ListNode[Any] = strList.prepend[Int](12345)
                                                   ^
```

See? If you *do* specify `Int`, it breaks. It worked in the original because `12345` was inferred as type `Any`, not as type `Int`.

Comment: Thank you for providing another example.